# Too Many commits in react profiler without renders

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-redux

This is baffling...

I have a particular event that fires in redux which modifies a portion of the state (typical stuff) but it is slow and linearly related to the number of DOM elements on the page.

I am using the react profiler to debug and seeing a ton of commits for different components. However, when putting console.logs in `render()` and `componentDidUpdate` functions I can confirm that the **components do not update nor render**. Why are there so many commits firing?

The confusing aspect of it is that according to the react documentation, **commits happen after render**

Please note that I am not supplying code because there is no particular snippet that makes sense to paste here. My question is more targeted toward understanding why commits happen without render

[image]

Comment: We need some code to evaluate that.

Comment: Hi I just edited my post. My question is more about why commits occur without render

Comment: The reason commits happen are because something is re-rendering over and over... Clicking on one of those green blocks should tell you why something is re-rendering. We either need code or a better screenshot of the profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was a bad version of `react-redux`. When updating to version `7.1.1` the problem went away and the number of commits reduced drastically.

I believe it is related to the change release in `v7.0.0-beta.0` which is [described here](https://inweb.notesalong.com/id/5d78622e4818060013b15a85/https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases?after=v7.0.2#notesalong:5d7861f4c928bd00004e1859;).